# Why does Haskell complain when I try to mix floor, division, and addition?

Tags: haskell

I have some code:

```
seqMin a b = (floor (a / b)) - (floor (b / 2.0  ))
seqMax a b = (seqMin a b) + b
test = seqMax 6 3
```

I expect `test` to be 1 when I evaluate it interactively.

When I evaluate my code, I get an error:

```
$ ghci split2.hs
```

> ```
> GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help [1 of 1]
> Compiling Main             ( split2.hs, interpreted )
>
> split2.hs:3:8: error:
>     • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘seqMax’
>       prevents the constraint ‘(RealFrac a0)’ from being solved.
>       Relevant bindings include test :: a0 (bound at split2.hs:3:1)
>       Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
>       These potential instances exist:
>         instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
>         instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
>         ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
>         (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
>     • In the expression: seqMax 6 3
>       In an equation for ‘test’: test = seqMax 6 3   | 3 | test = seqMax 6 3   |        ^^^^^^^^^^
>
> split2.hs:3:15: error:
>     • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘6’
>       prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
>       Relevant bindings include test :: a0 (bound at split2.hs:3:1)
>       Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
>       These potential instances exist:
>         instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
>         instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
>         instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
>         ...plus two others
>         ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
>         (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
>     • In the first argument of ‘seqMax’, namely ‘6’
>       In the expression: seqMax 6 3
>       In an equation for ‘test’: test = seqMax 6 3   | 3 | test = seqMax 6 3   |               ^ Failed, no modules loaded.
> ```

When trying to figure out why I got the error, I came up with another function:

```
f x = (floor (x/2)) + x
```

When I evaluate it, I get an error:

```
> f 3
```

> ```
> <interactive>:2:1: error:
>     • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
>       prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
>       Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
>       These potential instances exist:
>         instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
>         instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
>         instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
>         ...plus 22 others
>         ...plus 19 instances involving out-of-scope types
>         (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
>     • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
> ```

Why does this happen, how can I solve it, and how can I prevent it in the future? Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect the signature of `f` to be? Take a look at the type signature of `floor` and `(/)` -- what does these tell you (or really _not_ tell you) about what `x` and `f x` must be?

Comment: Have you tried adding the type annotations that the error messages suggest?

Comment: Have you considered using `div` and/or `quot` if you are only interested in integer results? (Related: can `a` or `b` ever be negative?)

Comment: `seqMin` takes two arguments of a `RealFrac` type and returns a value of an `Integral` type. `seqMax` tries to add that `Integral` result to one of the `RealFrac` arguments, resulting in a situation that is impossible to resolve (`RealFrac` and `Integral` are supposed to be disjoint.) Insert some numerical conversions somewhere, or don't use `floor`, `/`, and `2.0` (all of which require either `RealFrac` or `Fractional`).

Comment: @chepner I am relatively new to Haskell, so I was not aware those functions existed. a and b are expected to be positive integers such that a > b.

Answer (score 0):

The comments helped a lot. I changed `/` to `div` calls and it works now. Thanks everyone!