# Haskell - Use of mod-function does not work

Tags: haskell

I wanted to write a recursive power-function in haskell that uses the fact that b^(2e) = (b^2)^e and b^(2e+1)= b* (b^2)^e. Therefore, I needed to distinguish between even and odd exponents e.

I wrote a function using the inbuilt `mod`-function and a naive approach without other functions. Both implementations work fine for themselves but when I try to use them in my power function, only the naive implementation works and I don't understand why. Using the version with the 'mod'-function call throws errors and when I try to use the inbuilt `even`-function it also does not work.

I was wondering if maybe the expected and returned datatypes did not match in any way but I have too less experience in haskell to determine whether this actually is the problem nor to solve it.

So, first of all, here is the power-function, I want to implement.

```
pow b 0 = 1
pow b e = if isEven e then pow (b*b) (e/2) else b* pow (b*b) ((e-1)/2)
```

When using the following implementation of isEven, I get errors:

```
isEven n = n `mod` 2 == 0
```

But the function itself works fine. So directly calling "isEven 5" returns "False" as expected, but calling "pow 2 2" returns the following error:

```
<interactive>:30:1: error:
    * Could not deduce (Integral t0) arising from a use of `pow'
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the inferred type of it :: Num a => a
        at <interactive>:30:1-12
      The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Integral Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
        instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
        instance Integral Word -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the expression: pow (2) (2)
      In an equation for `it': it = pow (2) (2)

<interactive>:30:11: error:
    * Could not deduce (Num t0) arising from the literal `2'
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the inferred type of it :: Num a => a
        at <interactive>:30:1-12
      The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
        instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
        instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
        ...plus two others
        ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the second argument of `pow', namely `(2)'
      In the expression: pow (2) (2)
      In an equation for `it': it = pow (2) (2)
```

However, using the following naive version without other function calls everything seems to work:

```
isEven n
    | n < 0 = isEven (n+2)
    | n == 0 = True
    | n == 1 = False
    | otherwise = isEven (n-2)
```

So I can call "pow 2 2" and it returns "4" as expected.

I am very confused and would be happy if anyone could help me!

Comment: Tip: if you write type signatures you'll get much better error messages.

Comment: Also, consider `isEven 0.1`.

Comment: @Noughtmare Yes, I also thought about the type signatures but because I'm new to haskell I don't know which signatures would be appropriate.
And for the moment I need the isEven-function only for Integers, but I also don't know how to ensure this

Comment: For simplicity, I'd suggest starting out with `pow :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer` and `isEven :: Integer -> Bool`. (They can be made more polymorphic, but that tends to make it more confusing.) With a concrete constraint to `Integer`, the compiler can pinpoint the problem location much better.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Great, thank you. Now the compiler complains about the fact that the second argument of my recursive power call is created by a division and therefore not being an Integer ("Could not deduce (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of `/'"). I tried to fix this by using the floor-function or toInt but both do not work.

Comment: Good attempt, and that should point you to previous questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427264/why-does-haskell-complain-when-i-try-to-mix-floor-division-and-addition?rq=1

Comment: You might want to use library function [`divMod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#divMod). Gives you *both* integral quotient *and* remainder.

Comment: Thank you guys! Now by using \`div\` instead of the normal division / it finally works as intended.